# Rails query for record and latest association record efficiently with includes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm having trouble with a rails activerecord query.

I have 2 tables.

One for Projects:

```
id | name | created_at | updated_at
```

One for Project Reports:

```
id | project_id | number | created_at | updated_at
```

The corresponding class for Project:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :project_reports

  def latest_report_number
    project_reports.last.number
  end
end
```

And ProjectReports:

```
class ProjectReport < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
end
```

I'm attempting to write a query to get a list of the projects and the most recent report for the project.

I can do this in the following way, but this leads to a N+1 situation:

```
Project
  .select("projects.*, max(project_reports.created_at) as latest_report")
  .joins(:project_reports)
  .order("latest_report desc")
  .group("projects.id")
  .map { |p| "#{p.name}: #{p.latest_report_number}" }
```

I therefor wanted to use rails 'includes' feature so that I don't run into the N+1 situation:

```
Project
  .select("projects.*, max(project_reports.created_at) as latest_report")
  .joins(:project_reports)
  .order("latest_report desc")
  .group("projects.id")
  .includes(:project_reports)    # <----
  .map { |p| "#{p.name}: #{p.latest_report_number}" }
```

This causes my query to no longer work:

```
PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "project_reports.id" must appear in 
the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

How can I write my query so that I both accomplish the goal and limit the number of times I hit the database (ideally with includes)?

Comment: Why dont you just put "project_reports.id" in group by along with projects.id?

Comment: Because that would not provide me with unique project results. The same project would appear multiple times in the result set per report.

Comment: Why you are using `joins` along with `includes` in the second query?

Comment: The reason why I was trying to use it is stated clearly in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case of a join query, `includes` asks for extra columns from the associated table (i.e. `tasks`) in order to build the associated objects without an additional query. Normally, that's a welcome optimization, but in the case of a `GROUP BY` clause, you wind up with an invalid `SELECT`.

In your case, you want a completely separate query to load the associations, so `preload` is a better choice.

```
Project
  .select("projects.*, max(project_reports.created_at) as latest_report")
  .joins(:project_reports)
  .order("latest_report desc")
  .group("projects.id")
  .preload(:project_reports)
  .map { |p| "#{p.name}: #{p.latest_report_number}" }
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you sir!